# Loop in Grid EXTJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, edit

I have some store, which is formed data. On panel it looks how "fieldName" and text field (in depension from invoked form). For example, on one form is displayed "name document" and field, on another: date of selling and date field. Data is formed dynamicly

Here is store:

```
tableTempStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: objectUrlAddress,
    baseParams: {
        'objectID': objectID
    },
    root: 'Fields',
    fields: [{
        name: 'Type',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'Value'
    }, {
        name: 'IsRequired',
        type: 'bool'
    }, {
        name: 'Identifier'
    }, {
        name: 'Data'
    }],
    listeners: {
        load: function(obj, records) {
            Ext.each(records, function(rec) {

                var item = null;
                switch (rec.get('Type')) {
                    case 0:
                        item = new Ext.form.NumberField();
                        item.id = rec.get('Identifier');
                        item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                        var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                        item.anchor = '100%';
                        item.allowBlank = !isRequired;
                        item.disabled = editDisabled;
                        item.value = rec.get('Data');
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        item = new Ext.form.NumberField();
                        item.id = rec.get('Identifier');
                        item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                        var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                        item.anchor = '100%';
                        item.allowBlank = !isRequired;
                        item.allowDecimals = true;
                        item.disabled = editDisabled;
                        item.value = rec.get('Data');
                        break;
                }
                if (item != null) {
                    templateGrids.add(item);
                    columnsTable = item.__proto__.constructor.xtype;
                   source[item.fieldLabel] = '';
                    var s = null;
                    if (columnsTable == 'textfield')
                    {
                        s = 'textfield';
                        colm = {
                                xtype: s, 
                                id: item.id,
                                allowBlank: item.allowBlank, 
                                format: item.format,
                                value: item.value,
                                editable: true,
                                emptyText: item.emptyText,
                                disabled: item.disabled
                        };
                    }
                    else if (columnsTable == 'combo')
                    {
                        s = 'combo';
                        colm = {
                                xtype: s, 
                                id: item.id,
                                allowBlank: item.allowBlank, 
                                format: item.format,
                                value: item.value,
                                editable: true,
                                emptyText: item.emptyText,
                                disabled: item.disabled
                        };
                    }
                    else if (columnsTable == 'datefield')
                    {
                        s = 'datefield';
                        colm = {
                                xtype: s, 
                                id: item.id,
                                allowBlank: item.allowBlank, 
                                format: item.format,
                                value: item.value,
                                editable: true,
                                emptyText: item.emptyText,
                                disabled: item.disabled
                        };
                    }
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < templateGrids.getStore().data.length; i++) { 
                templateGrids.getColumnModel().setConfig([
                    {header: 'Name', id:'name', width:200}, 
                    {header:'Value', id:'val', dataIndex: rec.get('Value'), editable:true, width:200, editor: colm}]);
                    };
        }
    }
});
```

This code had worked in a form, but I need to use Grid (or Editor Grid). I know, how displayed field name ("document name" and etc.), but I don't understand, how displayed text field or etc. I try use loop, but on second column in xtype displayed last type in store. How i can resolve this problem?!

Here is a grid:

```
var templateGrids = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
        id: 'tableId',
        height:300,
        width: '100%',
        clicksToEdit:1,
        frame: true,
        store: tableTempStore,
        columns: [
        {header: 'Name'}, 
        {header: 'Value'}]
        });
```

Comment: Please post [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) to better explain your problem.

Comment: Will not work. I drop here just piece of code (very main), but i try to explaine again: i have a store with a set of values and fields. And one row in the table may have textfield, second - datefield. I create loop, but in setConfig saves only last iteration. And all columns have a datefield. How i can fixed this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property Grid in ExtJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950926/property-grid-in-extjs)